# I can't add an one dataset to another

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I used scikit-learn for training machine. I used method get_dummies for preparing dataset for Gradient Boosted Decision Tree alghorithm. And I have a test set which has less columns after get_dummies method (61001 rows × 8558 columns).
My test set has a shape: 61001 rows × 8558 columns.
My training set has a shape: 159880 rows × 12412 columns.
For using GBDT method for test set I need upgraded set with 12412 columns like a training set.
I decided creat: zero matrix with shape 61001 rows × 12412 columns:

```
X_test_zero = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((61001,12412)), 
                        columns = df3_train.columns)
```

where df3_train.columns - names of training set columns.
After that I want to use:
add method:

```
X_test = X_test_zero.add(df_test, fill_value=0)
```

Where: df_test dataframe with shape 61001 rows × 8558 columns and consists of: 0 or 1 (type: uint8).
And I get this error:
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 5.81 GiB for an array with shape (61001, 12776) and data type float64
How I can solve the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: That is way, way too many features (columns).  Also, your test and train sets MUST have the same number of features in order to evaluate the model.  Instead of using `get_dummies`, play around with your data and see if you can reduce the dimensionality before training a model.

Comment: Thank you James, for your advice. I elluminated excess data. But I am gooing to check it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is just a memory issue, data is too large for the available memory, one of the solutions may be by just using google colab which make you able to run on GPU's which is more practical by running in parallel instead of sequential running type, also i think you can train your model in batches of data (as in mini_batch in deep learning)

I found this comment looks helpful
https://github.com/lanagarmire/deepimpute/issues/12#issuecomment-556949884

best wishes.